# Techniques to prevent non-genuine clients from interacting with a server

Tags: security, authentication, client-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ensure a .Net application is genuine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774128/how-to-ensure-a-net-application-is-genuine)

I can't seem to find any good articles on this. In a client/server environment, is there any way to ensure that the clients connecting have not been tampered with?

The only two things I can think of doing are:

1. include a secret key in the genuine client, that is used in
   authentication, to prevent complete rewrites of the client
2. monitor the clients for behaviours that I believe deviate from
   what the genuine clients do

[1] does not prevent hacking, only rewrites. Plus presumably you can eventually find the key by looking through the bytecode?

[2] can be quite very tricky and sometimes subjective

Are there known techniques beyond the two above?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to ensure a .Net application is genuine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774128/how-to-ensure-a-net-application-is-genuine)

Looks like this has already been covered and the answer is a resounding: "There is no good way"

Feel free to close this question.